# How to update a Mapinfo layer at certain time intervalls?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have point which represents stress signal. The signal changes at certain time. How do I implement this in mapinfo ? I did this using time() function and increment it to certain seconds but whole application becomes busy which it is running the procedure. Is there other way?

[question on mapinfo-l](http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/a28cad194bba732d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a system service in VB which starts at your interval, updates and stops.  Use integrated mapping to .do and .eval the mapbasic commands.

Comment: Do we have any reference materials?  I searched on web and could not find material to get started :(

Comment: Not to hand, just lookk up building a polled service or something.  Integrated mapping is the other area you'd have to look into